# jQuery: Removing previous elements with content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given this markup:

```
<td>
   <a href="#">Item1</a> |
   <a href="#">Item2</a> |
   <a href="#">Item3</a> |
   <a href="#" class="refuseButton">Refuse</a>
   <div class="slideBox" style="display: none;">
        <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-sm-12">
                   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Description">
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

When I click on the `Refuse` link I want the previous elements along with its content (`|`) to be hide. I'm using `.prevAll()` but it removes the elements not the content:

```
$('.refuseButton').on('click', function(event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    $(this).prevAll().slideToggle();
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: wrap it with span, `<span>|</span>`

Comment: You can't do that without changing the html

Comment: wrap all the previous contents in an element/ or wrap the `|` in a span then hide all the previous elements

Comment: you can select that pipe with `this.previousSibling`

Comment: @Hacketo can you provide a fiddle with this? because as far I can tell: ".previousSibling is not a function"

Comment: @freedomn-m that's why I did not add `()` this is not a function but a [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling)

Comment: @Hacketo thanks for clarifying.  Get so used to using jquery all the time, forget some of the core js methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you can't change the markup (for whatever reason).

You can wrap the `textnodes` with a div on the fly and then hide the wrapping container.

You can't manipulate the `textnode` directly, so you have to wrap it, using `previousSibling` as recommended by Hacketo in the comments.

```
$('.refuseButton').on('click', function(event) {
    var sibs = [];
    var sib = this.previousSibling;
    while (sib) {
        sibs.push(sib);
        sib = sib.previousSibling;
    }
    $(sibs).each(function() {
        $(this).wrap("div").hide();
    });
});
```

This:

- collates all the nodes before the current node
- wraps each one in a div
- hides the div

The collate first is because wrapping *then* applying `.previousSibling` will always return null as there would no longer be any siblings.  (There are other ways to do this ofc - eg wrap them all then use jquery `.prevAll()` - or only wrap the textnodes using this technique - or just change the html (if possible)).

Obviously this won't be idempotent as it dynamically changes the html, but there are ways around that (eg only wrap text nodes, then there won't be any text nodes on subsequent calls).

Edit: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nbfm7eL3/)

Answer (score 1):

wrap all item lines with span. Run the snippet to see the result

```js
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.refuseButton').on('click', function(event) {
                var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
                $(this).prevAll().slideToggle();
                $(this).next().slideToggle();
            });           
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <span><a href="#">Item1</a> |</span>
  <span><a href="#">Item2</a> |</span>
  <span><a href="#">Item3</a> |</span>
  <a href="#" class="refuseButton">Refuse</a>
  <div class="slideBox" style="display: none;">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Description">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>            
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The | characters (known as pipes) are outside of the `a` tags. As far as HTML is concerned that's just plain text.

You'll have to move them into the `a` tags or wrap it all in a container like a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

You really can't change the HTML? Then it becomes difficult because you can't use the DOM to get to the '|' pipe symbols.

The following works by removing the

```
$('.refuseButton').on('click', function(event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    $(this).prevAll().slideToggle().remove();
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    content = $(this).parent().html();
    while(content.indexOf('|') != -1){
        content = content.replace('|', '');
    }
    $(this).parent().html(content);
});
```

Comment: "You can't use the DOM to get to the pipe" - see @Hacketo's comment and my answer for exactly how to do this

Comment: This solution doesn't use DOM to get to the pipe! However, your solution is certainly a lot cleaner than mine.

Answer (score 0):

How about Jquery.grep() solution:

```
$('.refuseButton').on('click', function(e) {
     $siblings=$($.grep($(e.target).parent().children('a'),function(item,index){
          return $(item).text() === '|'
}));
     $(siblings).remove() /*or $(siblings).text('') if you want to clear content*/
});
```

Also you can use `children('a:not(.refuseButton)')` in order to remove current click button